# Pushing out LGP to many machines without AD

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, group-policy

I have a school with 50 Windows machines that I would like to make edits to prevent the kids from changing the wallpapers ect... when they log into a student account.

We don't have a Windows Server and we use Windows XP SP3 to Windows 7. Is there a way I can make edits to the local user then push those policy rules out to every other machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a Microsoft Forums post ([here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/571603ea-e29c-4d59-93a0-cfacd1ce65df/gpo-export-and-import?forum=winserverGP)), there isn't any provision for exporting local policy directly. However it's possible to do this using the following steps:

1. Setup local policy as you want it on one machine. This machine is the template machine.
2. Copy the contents of the `%systemroot%\System32\grouppolicy` directory from your template machine to the same location on each of the machines you wish to apply the policy to.
3. Reboot client machine
4. Run the command `gpudate /force`

It should be noted that due to time constraints and a lack of access to the versions of Windows you are using, I haven't tested the method described here myself.

One could automate the deployment steps using a PowerShell script that remotes into each client, copies the template `grouppolicy` directory from a central location, adds a job to run the `gpupdate` command upon reboot and then reboots the machine.